# Erro compile 'com.android.support:support-v7:19.+'

Tags: android

Fiz a atualização hoje do android esta dando os seguintes erros

> Error:com.android.support:support-v4:19.+
>   `<a href="searchInBuildFiles">Search in build.gradle files</a>`

Aí eu dou duplo click OK mais vou executar aparece o seguinte

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-v4:19.+.
>        Required by:
>            Casa_Monitoramento:app:unspecified

OBS: baixei o Android suporte library 19.1 e o tools SDK 19.1

Comment: Usando o Android Studio?

Comment: Sim! estou dando uma pesquisada pode ser pq não instalei o Android Support Repository 5?

Comment: Veja isso: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19958213/how-to-add-android-support-repository-to-android-studio

Comment: traduzir o conteúdo do post que eu mencionei, poderia verificar se resolve seu problema? Desculpe, mas não disponho de meios para simular seu problema agora.

Comment: Obrigado Pessoal consegui resolver precisava mesmo Baixar o Android Support Repository e dar um Restart no cogido que deu certo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solução encontrada:

1. Vá para onde o SDK (que o android studio/eclipse está utilizando) está localizado.
   Se for o Android studio, vá para `extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\`.
   Se for o eclipse, vá para `\extras\android\support\`
2. Veja quais pastas você possue, no exemplo ele possuía `gridlayout-v7`, `support-v4` e `support-v13`.
3. Click em `support-v4` e veja qual é o número da pasta seguinte, no exemplo foi nomeada para `13.0`

Desde que você esteja usando "com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+", troque isso para refletir a versão que você possui, por exemplo, aqui temos `support-v4` então a primeira parte v4 permanece a mesma. Uma vez que o próximo caminho é 13.0, troque seu 18.0 também:

```
"com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+"
```

Atualização:

Eu notei que eu tinha o android studio criado com o SDK errado e foi isso que causou a dificuldade na atualização! O caminho deve ser C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\extras\

Além disso, observe se o seu SDK está atualizado, o código será:

```
"com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+"
```

Fonte: [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19958213/how-to-add-android-support-repository-to-android-studio)